# NSDateFormatter for 2015-02-13 17:16:00 +0000

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSString *value = [newProperties objectForKey:key]
NSLog(@"%@",value);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzzz"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:value];
```

**value** is `2015-02-13 17:16:00 +0000`
But I am getting crash in last line which says :

```
'-[__NSTaggedDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe41ba8e68d000000'
```

Comment: `value` is already an `NSDate`, not an `NSString`. There's nothing to convert.

Comment: BTW - If you actually did need to convert a string with that format, don't set the timezone on the date formatter and change the `zzzz` to `Z`.

Comment: @maddy: value is a string which has a date in it.

Comment: @maddy: I tried with Z too. Not working.

Comment: No. `value` is not a string. It is an `NSDate`. If it really was an `NSString` you wouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: You are calling the **length** which is not able to call. Because the sender is **NSDate**

Comment: @maddy: How may I make you believe value is a string.

Comment: @nitish NSLog(@"Value class: %@", [value class]);

Comment: I have written two more lines on top from my code. Please check.

Comment: `[newProperties objectForKey:key];` can return anything. Please provide the output of `[value class]`.

Comment: More specifically, `value` is a `__NSTaggedDate`.

Comment: @Nitish When you log an `NSDate`, it looks exactly like the output you are seeing. Do what "mbogh" stated and log `[value class]`. It won't be a string class. It will be a date class.

Comment: Everyone : My mistake. class is coming out to be NSDate. I apologize.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: By the way, if indeed you *were* converting a string date, you've got the wrong date format.  "hh" means a 12-hour clock, and it will choke on "17" for the hour.  You should use "HH".

Comment: @HotLicks : How is this a duplicate of what you have mentioned?

Comment: It's about "unrecognized selector", and how to debug that.  (Why do you think rmaddy knew right away that you already had an NSDate?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is clearly showing that `value` is already an `NSDate`, not an `NSString`.

All of your code can be replaced with one line:

```
NSDate *value = [newProperties objectForKey:key];
```

You can verify that `value` is a date by logging its class:

```
NSLog(@"value class = %@", [value class]);
```

As a side note. If you really did have a date string in the format shown, your format specifier would need to be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z`.