# Add part of NSArray to other NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm trying to add part of a large `NSArray` to another `NSArray`. However, I'm doing something wrong since it keeps throwing errors.

This is the specific code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searches;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *chosenResult;

...bit further down...

for (NSString *string in self.searches[indexPath.row]) {
    [self.chosenResult addObject:string];
}
```

This is the error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Search countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a1710d0'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: It's really not. I know what the error means, I just don't know how to pass the content of the array at that point to another array.

Comment: Well, for us to have a clue as to how to help you, you'd have to reveal the structure of your source array, including the structure of the `Search` class which you appear to be using instances of.

Comment: (You clearly don't know what "unrecognized selector" means if you don't realize that there's a `Search` instance in the mix.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a disconnect between what you think you have in your data structure and what you **actually** have in your data structure. The error is telling you that you are trying to send the message `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` (a fast enumeration method)  to a `Search` object.

That tells us that your self.searches array contains `Search` objects, not dictionaries as you say it does. (Or at least that the object at the target index is a Search object. Objects at other indexes could be some other type...) I suggest doing some more debugging to figure out why the array contains something different than you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just don't need the fast enumeration loop, because you already have the index into the array:

```
[self.chosenResult addObject:self.searches[indexPath.row]];
```

The error that you see is because the fast enumeration loop is expecting some collection, like an array, but you're actually providing it a `Search` object which doesn't implement the fast enumeration methods.

Comment: It's an array of NSDictionaries.

Comment: What is? The error shows it is an array of `Search` objects. If it was an array of dictionaries then it should work fine to enumerate the dictionary keys.