# iOS, NSString property confused as being UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

**.h**

```
@interface HuntProfileView : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *huntgroupTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *huntgroupId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *lines;
@end
```

**.m**

```
@interface HuntProfileView ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *huntgrouptitleText;
@property HuntLineTable *childView;
@end

@implementation HuntProfileView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"huntgroupTitle %@", self.huntgroupTitle);
    self.huntgrouptitleText.text = self.huntgroupTitle;
}
```

**instantiation, assignment & execution**

```
^{
    HuntProfileView *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HUNTVIEW"];
    viewController.huntgroupId = huntId;
    viewController.huntgroupTitle = title;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
 }
```

`viewController.huntgroupTitle = title;` is correct, or at least title is the string as expected.

The NSLog in `.m` outputs as:

```
2015-01-21 09:47:42.267 changeView[1108:16196] huntgroupTitle <UITextField: 0x7fa9a8fc8480; frame = (16 63; 568 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa9a8fc9c70>>
2015-01-21 09:47:42.267 changeView[1108:16196] -[UITextField rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9a8fc8480
2015-01-21 09:47:42.270 changeView[1108:16196] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9a8fc8480'
```

**Update:**
I'm able to get successful execution when assigning `self.huntgroupTitle` a literal string ("hello, world"). Debugging has shown that at instantiation, both the input string of `title` as well as `viewController.huntgroupTitle` are confirmed to be the correct type.

Comment: you should  put a breakpoint at "viewController.huntgroupTitle = title;" and inspect title. If that doesnt work override the setter for "huntgroupTitle" and put a breakpoint there to check when it is assigned.

Comment: problem is not in your `ViewDidLoad` , check where u add the `rangeOfCharacterFromSet` in **.m**

Comment: Need more code. This usually happens when you accidentally assign the variable of an `NSString` type to a variable of type `UITextField`.

Comment: break point & variable inspection shows types are correct at that point.

Comment: i myself never call `rangeOfCharacterFromSet`. which function does utilize it so i can pin point the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: @Hot Licks the debugger didn't give me the answer to this, nor any useful insight. It was only as a last thought that i should check the storyboard source. This question has been resolved with my own answer, of which i'm unable to accept untill 2 days time

Comment: The exception message told you what you needed to know -- you were assigning the wrong type of object.  What you're calling an "NSString" is a UITextField.

Comment: i disagree with you for the reason that all debug testing achieved was to inform me that somehow, the NSString property was being received as UITextView. no indication of location, or anything more. 
In all honestly, i'm getting sick of the negative response from this community. I explained my situation & gave everything available to me, and even provided the solution to it, of which non of the other answers were capable. yet all i received is criticism.

Comment: Maybe it's time that you learned how to debug.  Start by learning how to get the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

While initialising the `HuntProfileView` you must be assigning a `UITextField` to `huntgroupTitle`. Please check that.

I guess you might be doing something like this

```
HuntProfileView *huntV = [[HuntProfileView alloc] init];
huntV.huntgroupTitle = **some UITextField**;
```

instead it should be

```
HuntProfileView *huntV = [[HuntProfileView alloc] init];
huntV.huntgroupTitle = someTextField.text;
```

Please check. Thanks

Comment: i'm not, my only use of the properties in question has been posted above.

Comment: Please check the type for `title` while you do `viewController.huntgroupTitle = title;`

Comment: i did, and i've mentioned that in my question. this issue has been resolved, see my answer.

Comment: Ok great then... Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

The Storyboard source file had:

```
<connections>
  <outlet property="huntgroupTitle" destination="wx0-NH-iGn" id="P9H-Oe-AEm"/>
  <outlet property="huntgrouptitleText" destination="wx0-NH-iGn" id="Z1E-9e-lEn"/>
</connections>
```

Removing line with property `"huntgroupTitle"` resolved this