# Getting JSON Sub Category Element Issue

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm retreving JSON data and I've some categories name with sub_category and other without `=0`. I can get the categories name and it is working fine but I couldn't get the `name` in the `sub_category`, It is getting crash when I call `_arraySubCategory` Error: `reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Am I calling the method right? Where would be my issue?

```
- (IBAction)getData:(id)sender {

NSString *string = BaseURLString;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    _dic  = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

    NSLog(@"Data %@", _dic);

    for (NSDictionary *dict in [_dic objectForKey:@"categories"]) {

        [_arrayName addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];

        _dicSubCategory = [dict objectForKey:@"sub_category"];

        [_arraySubCategory addObject:[_dicSubCategory objectForKey:@"name"]]; //Crashing

        NSLog(@"%@", _dicSubCategory);
    }


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog("No Connection")

  }];

    [operation start];   
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_arrayName count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

JSON Data:

```
{
  categories =     (
            {
        name = "Shop By Room";
        "sub_category" =             (
                            {
                name = "BEDROOM";
                "sub_category" = 0;
            },
                           {
                name = "LIVING ROOM";
                "sub_category" = 0;
            }
        );
    },
            {
        name = "Drinkware";
        "sub_category" =             (
                            {
                name = "Glass1";
                "sub_category" = 0;
            },
                            {
                name = "Glass2";
                "sub_category" = 0;
            },

            {
        name = "Service";
        "sub_category" = 0;
    },
            {
        name = "Design";
        "sub_category" =             (
                            {
                name = "RA";
                "sub_category" = 0;
            },
                            {
                name = "SW";
                "sub_category" = 0;
            }
        );
    },
            {
        name = "Collections";
        "sub_category" = 0;

            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `(` marks the begin of an NSArray.  If you look at the original JSON that would be a `[` character.  You need to index an array, not access it by key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sorry I get confused may I ask now I've changed the `_dicSubCategory ` to `_arraySubCategory` (array). Could you please explain more?

Comment: `_dicSubCategory` is not a dictionary.  The type of the variable is (mostly) irrelevant -- what's important is the type of the object the variable addresses, and that is an array.  It's an array because the value of "sub_category" is an array (as can be seen by the `(` character).

Comment: If you have a box labeled "dog" and put a cat in it, the cat does not turn into a dog.

Comment: @HotLicks  Finally It is started to work. I'm only getting an error ` this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.` when the value is equal to zero for example "sub_category" = 0; in `Service` & `Collections`. How I can fix it please?

Comment: That's essentially the same error as "unrecognized selector", only different.  The zero value comes through as an NSNumber, and you must test the type of the value coming back from fetching "sub_category" to see whether it's an NSNumber or an NSArray.  You can test the type with, eg `if ([theSubCategoryValue isKindOfClass: [NSNumber class]])`.

Comment: @HotLicks can you please write your answer? So I accept the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(` marks the beginning of an NSArray. If you look at the original JSON that would be a `[` character. You need to index an array, not access it by key.

This means that `_dicSubCategory` is not a dictionary, regardless of how the variable is declared. The type of the variable is (mostly) irrelevant -- what's important is the type of the object the variable addresses, and that is an array. It's an array because the value of "sub_category" is an array (as can be seen by the `(` character).

If you have a box labeled "dog" and put a cat in it, the cat does not turn into a dog.

`this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.`

That's essentially the same error as "unrecognized selector", only different. The zero value for "sub_category" comes through as an NSNumber, and you must test the type of the value coming back from fetching "sub_category" to see whether it's an NSNumber or an NSArray. You can test the type with, eg:

```
if ([theSubCategoryValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
```