# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when connecting Navigation View Controller via root view controller to Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6

I want to start with a DetailViewController, not a Table View.

[image]

1. So, first I create a Master-Detail Application.

[image]

2. Then, I remove the Segue

[image]

3. Control-drag from Nav Controller to Detail View Controller and select "root view controller"

[image]

4. Nav is now directly connected to Detail View Controller

[image]

5. **unrecognized selector sent to instance**

I'm confused because I've always done it like this in XCode5... And now it doesn't work anymore?? Some help is much appreciated guys :).

**Update: When UNCHECKING Core Data at project creation, it doesn't happen. But I do need Core Data!!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that someone is trying to call `setManagedObjectContext` on a `DetailViewController` instance and this method doesn't exist. Thus resulting in a runtime crash.

Comment: When searching for this function, it appears not to be present in this directory??

Answer (score 0):

Had almost similar issue (With view controllers). If you have some view controllers with segues connected and data transfer happens in between. Make sure the data to the required view controller is set with the prepareForSegue separately for each destination view controller.