# setting NSString text in iOS UIAlertView crashing, get error __NSCFNumber _isNaturallyRTL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, uialertview

I am using a NSString output of a `NSMutableArray` to put as text for a `UIAlertView`, to appear as the default text.

I find that I have to recreate an `NSString` from the `NSString` coming from the dictionary, otherwise it creates an 'NSInvalidArgumentException'.

Specifically, when I call:

```
NSMutableArray *serverResponseNumbers;
...
UIAlertView *alertviewmod=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Modify" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Confirm",nil];
[alertviewmod setDelegate:self];
alertviewmod.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;  //two text fields
[alertviewmod textFieldAtIndex:0].keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
NSString *nsRecordNumber=[serverResponseNumbers objectAtIndex:an_int_variable];
...
[alertviewmod textFieldAtIndex:0].text= nsRecordNumber;
```

I get this exception:

```
-[__NSCFNumber _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde4dbf0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde4dbf0'
```

Just to 'prove' it (assuming NSLog proves it), the following works:

```
NSLog(@"nsRecordNumber=%@",nsRecordNumber);
```

or the following line works fine it its place:

```
[alertviewmod textFieldAtIndex:0].text= @"static text";
```

What I find fixes it, but is rather inelegant, is to recreate the `NSString`.  In my case this string is just of an integer number, so I can use this hack:

```
     int number=[nsRecordNumber integerValue];
     NSString *nsNumberRecreated=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number];
     [alertviewmod textFieldAtIndex:0].text= nsNumberRecreated;
```

But this really shouldn't be needed.  And I read that '_isNaturallyRTL' is an undocumented function.  Can anyone explain this?  Perhaps something wrong I'm doing, or a bug?  I am using `XCode` 4.6, targeting `iOS` 4.3, and testing on an `iPad` with `iOS` 5.1.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: You're trying to use a NSNumber to set the `text` property which is declared to expect an NSString.

Comment: My apologies, I used a confusing variable name with 'Number' inside the NSString variable name.  It is an NSString, not a number or NSNumber that I am adding to the Alert text box.

Comment: No, you are adding an NSNumber, as can be clearly seen from the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that nsRecordNumber is actually a NSNumber instead of a NSString. That would explain why the NSLog works but setting the text doesn't. If that is a case you can do.

```
[alertviewmod textFieldAtIndex:0].text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nsRecordNumber];
```

That is basically what you are doing in your NSLog.

Edit: A better choice would be.

```
[alertviewmod textFieldAtIndex:0].text= [nsRecordNumber stringValue];
```

Try doing this to very that it is actually a NSString or NSNumber.

```
if ([nsRecordNumber isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
    NSLog(@"it is a number");
}
else if([nsRecordNumber isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    NSLog(@"it is a string");
}
```

Hopefully that helps fix the issue. As far as where _isNaturallyRTL is coming from I do not know.

Comment: One should not use `description` to generate "user" text -- except for some specific classes, description is intended only for diagnostics.  Instead use the appropriate method (`intValue`, `floatValue`, etc) of NSNumber to extract the value, then the appropriate `%` formatting code to format it.

Comment: @HotLicks is correct using the description isn't an ideal way to handle this and I updated my answer. There is however a stringValue method on NSNumber you can use or go about it the way he suggested. I would recommend checking nsRecordNumber and verify if it is a NSString as you originally thought or a NSNumber as I suspect.