# Creating a User object instead of an NSEntityDescription object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new to Objective-C . I am trying to send an object of type User(made with core data) from SingupViewController to its delegate ViewController. However I get this error that you get from what I've read because I am double instantiating memory for the same object ? . The error is as follows :

```
[User managedObjectModel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ca90560
2015-03-14 03:44:49.613 Honk2[302:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[User managedObjectModel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ca90560'
```

The code for `SingupViewController.h` is :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "User.h"


@protocol SingupDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)signUp;
- (void)cancelPressDel;
- (void)savePress:(User *)addUser;

@end

@interface SingupViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SingupDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

The code for `SingupViewController.m` is:

```
import "SingupViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CoreViewController.h"

@interface SingupViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
{

    UILabel *titleApp;

    UITextField *username;
    UITextField *password;
    UITextField *email;
    UIButton *signUp;
    UIButton *cancel;
}
    @property(strong,nonatomic)User *thenewUser;

@end

@implementation SingupViewController
-(void)onSignUpPressed{

    _thenewUser.name = username.text;
    _thenewUser.email = email.text;
    _thenewUser.password = password.text;

    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(savePress:)]) {
        [[self delegate] savePress:_thenewUser];

    }

}

@end
```

The code for `ViewController.h` is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CoreViewController.h"
#import "User.h"

@interface ViewController : CoreViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@end
```

And the code for `ViewController.m` is:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "SingupViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CoreViewController.h"


@interface ViewController () <LoginDelegate, SingupDelegate>
{
    LoginViewController *login;
    SingupViewController *singup;
}
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObject;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void)savePress:(User *)addUser{

    NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    NSManagedObject *newUser = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:description insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    [newUser setValue:addUser.name forKey:@"name"];
    [newUser setValue:addUser.email forKey:@"email"];
    [newUser setValue:addUser.password forKey:@"password"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if(![newUser.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"invatam si noi sa codam?");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Hai ca am invatam sa codat");
    }


    [self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideTopBottom];
}
-(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext{
    return[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
}
```

The `User.h` is the one given by Xcode :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Tweet;

@interface User : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *tweets;
@end

@interface User (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addTweetsObject:(Tweet *)value;
- (void)removeTweetsObject:(Tweet *)value;
- (void)addTweets:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeTweets:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

And this is the `User.m` also not touched:

```
#import "User.h"
#import "Tweet.h"


@implementation User

@dynamic email;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic password;
@dynamic tweets;

@end
```

The error happens when I try to save the object. Can anyone tell me what I am allocating wrong ? Or what the fault is ?

Comment: Could you post some code about `User` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are sending a `managedObjectModel` to your `User` object and `User` cannot respond to that.

What's happening is when instantiating an `NSEntityDescription` you should use the following code:

`[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];`

What you are doing is instantiating a `User` object not an `NSEntityDescription` object. Then this line:

`NSManagedObject *newUser = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:description insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];`

the `description` is actually a `User` object not an `NSEntityDescription` object.

EDIT a few pointers:

1) in the `onSignUpPressed` if possible you should make a new user and add it to the context there and then but if you really want to call `savePress:` do this:

```
-(void)onSignUpPressed{

    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(savePress:)]) {
        [[self delegate] savePress:@{@"UName":username.text, @"Email":email.text, @"PWord":password.text}];

    }
}
```

What you are doing here is sending a dictionary with all the appropriate values to the delegate.

Then in the `savePress:`

```
-(void)savePress:(NSDictionary *)dict{

    NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    NSManagedObject *newUser = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:description insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    [newUser setValue:dict[@"UName"] forKey:@"name"];
    [newUser setValue:dict[@"Email"] forKey:@"email"];
    [newUser setValue:dict[@"PWord"] forKey:@"password"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if(![newUser.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"invatam si noi sa codam? Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Hai ca am invatam sa codat");
    }


    [self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideTopBottom];
}
```

When you use CoreData you really need to have a structure that is planned and that you stick to.

Comment: User *newUser = [[User alloc] initWithEntity:description insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]; doing this doesn't fix it either . How can I save newUser in the DB ?

Comment: It's because the `description` variable isn't an `NSEntityDescription` the return value for `NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];` is a `User` object not a `NSEntityDescription` object. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEntityDescription/entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:)

Comment: wait, I get what you are saying. Thank you very much RASS , sorry I shall try to pay more attention in the future , I was just following a tutorial and I was trying to add stuff that I heard so I kinda get stuck sometimes .. since I  don't go along with the tutorial 100%

Comment: _thenewUser.email = email.text; why doesn't it give the email.text value to _thenewUser.email ? if you have the spare time:D

Comment: Having a look I can't see any code for instantiating _thenewUser, so as far as I can see you are setting the values to a nil reference. What you need to do is:`self.thenewUser = [User alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];` just before you set the values.

Comment: you are perfectly right, I was trying to do it like _newUser = [[User alloc] init] and xcode was being mean to me :. Thank you very much again!