# How to resolve exception -[UIImage scaleToSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am getting an image from gallery and displaying it in the `collectionViewCell`. When user clicks the `collectionViewCell` that image is dimply into `anotherView`. I have `tableView` which is having filters (Effects) to apply when I click `tableViewCell`. But here I am getting exception. My code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.imageView.image = inputImage11;
    self.secImgView.image = secblurImage;

    arrEffects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Original", @"title", @"", @"method", nil],
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Brightness", @"title", @"e1", @"method", nil],
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"BoardWalk", @"title", @"e2", @"method", nil], nil
    ];
    //here getting this Exception
    thumbImage = [inputImage11 scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, 300.0f)];
    minithumbImage = [thumbImage scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
}
```

I tried googling the issue but have not found a solution. Can anybody please suggest a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does the inputImage11 come from? Apparently it is supposed to be a UIImage instance which it is not.

Comment: i want to display image into collectionViewcell thats why i declared like that

Comment: Do you create it as a property in your .h class? Where do you initialize it? Is it created in storyboard?

Comment: Where are you getting that scaleToSize is an instance method of UIImage. The doc's don't show any method, class or instance, of that name. Hence you will get a unrecognised selector sent to instance

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/

Comment: if i wrote like this     thumbImage = [self.imageView.image scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f,300.0f)];

Comment: even getting same error

Comment: There is no method called scaleToSize:

Comment: i am using third party api for filters and import them into my file then i am using now

Comment: What third party api you are using and how you add it? You problem is that this library doesn't implement that

Comment: Is it crashing on the first or second time you are calling `scaleToSize`?

Comment: k thank you for your valuable information

Comment: At the time of first only its crashing

Comment: So if you comment `thumbImage = [inputImage11 scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, 300.0f)];` you get no exception?

Comment: In that line getting crash

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: The problem is quite simple.  **UIImage does not have a method named `scaleToSize:`.**

Comment: @HotLicks author has mentioned that he is using 3d party library but didn't said which one

Comment: @Azat - Hopefully UIImage is not a 3rd-party class, since it's an essential class in iOS.

Comment: The message is telling you that you're attempting to use the method `scaleToSize:` on an object of class UIImage, and there is no such method on that class.  The most obvious reason for this would be that either `inputImage11` or `thumbImage` (or both) is a UIImage rather than some subclass of UIView.

Comment: @iosDev82 - Your comment is backwards.  The problem is that at least one of those two `...Image` pointers *is* pointing at a UIImage.

Comment: sorry for the late reply dudes..

Comment: i am using image filters third party api files those are UIImage+Filttr.h, .m,

Comment: UIImage+FilterCompositions.h,UIImage+FilterCompositions.m , UIImage+Scale.h

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your line with the following:

```
thumbImage = [self imageWithImage:inputImage11 scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, 300.0f)];
```

And add this method to your class:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Credit: @Paul Lynch for the method.

Also, these are some categories you should look at: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: getting error like NO visible @interface secondViewController declares the selector imageWithImage:scaleToSize:'

Comment: You need to put the method in the same view controller where you are calling it. If not you need to create a helper class.

Comment: i want to call this method in same viewController..actaully my requirement is i have an image in viewController which having tableView also so when we click tableviewCell we want to apply filter effect to image..similarly when i click another tableviewcell some other filter effect will be applied ..

Comment: Dude there is nothing in your code above about filters. You asked about scaling to fit and I showed you how to do that.