# AFNetworking with JSON giving objectForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I am trying to access my JSON and I get that part done. But when I want access a particular item in the JSON, I get the

```
    '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here is the following code:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCredential:credentials];
    [operation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
        jsonOutputData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:responseObject];
        NSLog(@"%@", [[jsonOutputData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"comments"]);

        NSLog(@"The Array: %@",jsonOutputData);

        //[self.newsFeed reloadData];

    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];
```

And my JSON is pretty simple:

```
   [  
    {  
  "id":"2043",
  "user_id":"5",
  "created_time":"2015-03-24 22:32:58",
  "post_type":"3",
  "post_link":"google.ca",
  "message":null,
  "photo":{  
     "height":"266",
     "width":"720",
     "link":"google.ca",
     "thumbnail":"jpg",
     "source":"jpg"
  },
  "likes":"88029",
  "shares":"170",
  "comments":"850",
   }
 ]
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated! If there are any questions, please ask and I will try my best to give you the necessary information!

Thanks

Here is the JSON output

```
    (
       (
            {
        comments = 868;
        "created_time" = "2015-03-24 22:32:58";
        id = 2043;
        likes = 88309;
        message = "<null>";
        photo =             {
            height = 266;
            link = "google.ca";
            thumbnail = "jpg";
            width = 720;
        };
        "post_link" = "google.ca";
        "post_type" = 3;
        shares = 175;
        "user_id" = 5;
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: Could you output `jsonOutputData` and paste the result?

Comment: (
        (
                {
            comments = 868;
            "created_time" = "2015-03-24 22:32:58";
            id = 2043;
            likes = 88309;
            message = "<null>";
            photo =             {
                height = 266;
                link = "google.ca";
                thumbnail = "jpg";
                width = 720;
            };
            "post_link" = "google.ca";
            "post_type" = 3;
            shares = 175;
            "user_id" = 5;
        }

Comment: Do you know the difference between an NSDIctionary and an NSArray???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `jsonOutputData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:responseObject];`. So you're putting your `responseObject` array into a new array (so you have an array in an array). Then you get the first item out of the array, which is `responseObject` - an array - and try to access it as a dictionary.

Just do

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[responseObject objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"comments"]);
```

Comment: How would I use the responseObject in a table view? Since its local instance to the completion block. 

Could I copy the responseObject to another array using:

        jsonOutputData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[responseObject copy]];

And then use that for the table View?

Comment: You don't need to copy the array as you create a mutable array with it. Simply `jsonOutputData = [responseObject mutableCopy]` will do. You also don't really need it to be mutable just to source a table view.