# How to extract data from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

Want to extract value from the `NSMutableArray`

After services call I got response which is stored in `NSMutableArray`

```
`arrayList` = responseData
```

The response data is an **JSON string**

Below is response data structure:

```
 {
        firstSet =     (
        );
        secondSet =     {
            id = 12;
            name = rohan;
        };
        "status_code" = 200;
        success = 1;
    }
```

I want to extract `name` field and `id` from the `arrayList`.
This is what I tried, not working me.

```
[[[arrayList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"secondSet"] objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

Error Message
**-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c6763e0**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: to solve it I need to declear NsMutableArray to NSmutablDictionary... from there i can extract the values!?

Comment: To solve you need to not assign an NSDictionary address to an NSArray pointer.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree what you say,  And also i got the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The variable you're referring to as "arraylist" is actually a Dictionary.  Try asking it for "secondset"

```
[[arrayList objectForKey:@"secondSet"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: the variable which i defined is a NSMutableArray Not NSMutableDictionary,

Comment: Doesn't matter what it's defined as - somehow (through the JSON deserializer maybe?) the reference is pointing to a dictionary.  The error indicates as such.  Since all Objective-C references are just pointers, and not checked, it's easy at runtime to have something pointing to the wrong object type.

Comment: @kiran - The running code doesn't care how you defined the pointer -- that's only meaningful to the compiler, and then only if it's right.  The object type is defined by the JSON data.

Answer (score -3):

you would be getting `json` which you may handle like this

```
NSDictionary *dic;
if (data!=nil)
    {
        dic = [NSJSONSerialization
               JSONObjectWithData:data //1
               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
               error:&error];
    }
NSString *name = [[dic objectForKey:@"second"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: He already has it parsed.  And you fail to demonstrate proper error checking anyway.