# XCode NSDictionary error - objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, uitableview

I have a table view in my XCode (IOS) that is passing data to my second table view

**FirstTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSecond"]){
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      SecondViewController *List = segue.destinationViewController;
      List.cat = [myObjectCat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   }
}
```

**SecondTableViewController.h**: This is what I have

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSDictionary *cat;
```

**SecondTableViewController.m**

```
for (NSDictionary *clickresult in cat) {
    NSString *title_cat = [clickresult objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@", title_cat);
}
```

When running the code I get the following error:

> WebService[7153:90b] 0 WebService[7153:90b] -[__NSCFConstantString
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ae0
>   WebService[7153:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ae0'

This is what I see on the left side of the debugger when running the code

```
cat = (_NSDictionaryl *) class name = _NSDictionaryl 
 -> [0] = @"name" : @"This is my first title"
 -> [1] = @"icon" : @"icon.png"
```

What do I need to do to get both the name and icon values of the element passed (cat) to the second table view controller?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: Without knowing what `cat` is, it's impossible to say specifically why it's failing.  (And note that the debugger display is unreliable -- you must either use NSLog or do `po cat` in the console.)

Comment: How is this a duplicate? You guys worry more about this than trying to help answering questions. Sad :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue

```
NSString *myTitle = [cat objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *myIcon = [cat objectForKey:@"icon"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got your issue. You are using a weak property

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSDictionary *cat;
```

for your variable `cat`. It will be released  just after you initialize it. Try using `strong` for it

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *cat;
```

Hope this solves it