# setImage: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimagepickercontroller

I am doing this online swift course and now I am trying to combine two different projects with each other to create my own project. Basically I had a task manager app but now I want to add an image to each task.

I can't get my head around the following:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TaskModel", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let taskItem = TaskModel(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        taskItem.image = imageData;
        (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).saveContext()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
```

When I run my app I get the following error:

2015-06-10 20:43:59.726 TaskIt[85735:13802555] -[TaskModel setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x792a4800

I figured out that when I comment out taskItem.image = imagaData; the code works. But I cant figure out what's wrong.

Anyone that can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error -- It's written for Objective-C but the same principles apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `TaskModel` class does not have an `image` property, and so you can't call `setImage:` on an object of this class (which is what `taskItem.image =` actually does.)

Comment: Thanks! Im mister stupid here, selected the wrong model version for my db that did not include image