# -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }

    if (cell.tag == 0)
    {

    }

    str = [jsonData objectAtIndex:cell.tag];

    NSDictionary *dict = [jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblDeliveryTime.text = [dict valueForKey:@"sysord_ExpectedDeliveryTime"];
    cell.lblOrderPlacedTime.text = [dict valueForKey:@"sysord_OrderDateTime"];
    cell.lblDeliveryPickUP.text = [dict valueForKey:@"sysord_DeliveryType"];

    NSDictionary *dict1 = [jsonData objectAtIndex:cell.tag];

    orderidString = [dict1 valueForKey:@"sysord_ID"];

    DetailViewController *detailVC=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?  (Hint: step through with the debugger to find out.)

Comment: Which line exactly? I guess that's one of the three "cell.ZzZ.text" or `orderidString`. The value from `dict` (or `dict1`) is a `NSNumber` and you use it as it was a `NSString`.

Comment: You haven't set tag to cell, and trying to access values based on cell.tag. It will not work.  Also you are assigning [jsonData objectAtIndex:cell.tag] to str as well as dict1. Its not clear. What is happening here. However [jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] make sense as indexpath will generate automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 4):

One of the values is not a `NSString` but `NSNumber`.

I would advise you to first check the type but if you want to always convert to string, you can use:

```
cell.lblDeliveryPickUP.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dict[@"sysord_DeliveryType"]];
```

Comment: @Droppy Ideally, you wouldn't even keep the data as JSON. You would parse it beforehand to an object with properties with correct types.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign an object from dictionary to a `text`, you need to make sure it's a NSString type.

```
cell.lblDeliveryTime.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"sysord_ExpectedDeliveryTime"] stringValue];
cell.lblOrderPlacedTime.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"sysord_OrderDateTime"] stringValue];
cell.lblDeliveryPickUP.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"sysord_DeliveryType"] stringValue];
```