# unrecognised selector sent to instance when using IQDropDownTextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQDropDownTextField library for drop down.

I have followed the steps given in documentation but getting exception

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField setIsOptionalDropDown:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance`

I also created bridging header for it.

I want to know what exactly this exception describes? Why and when this is occurring? How can I resolve this issue?

Note: I am using SWIFT programming language

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: @HotLicks it's not duplicate. It's specifically related to `IQDropDownTextField`. and below answer helped me to resolve it. If you take it as debugging then it will be a sub question of mine question Hopefully you appreciate it.

Comment: You said "I want to know what exactly this exception describes? Why and when this is occurring?"  The dupe question explains this very well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created your textfield outlet as `IQDropDownTextField` Outlet

if not

Try this

In your storyboard select your textfield and then select identity inspector and then in class write `IQDropDownTextField` and then create outlet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It was dumbest mistake. Fixed it. Thanks. But it not give me description of this exception, how you traced it that I was missed something. Solution worked perfectly but can explain what this error exactly describe ?

Comment: @RockStar Basically says the text field has no such method.