# cellForRowAtIndexPath does not called after first time and gives error [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return dict.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RestaurantResultsCell";
  RestaurantDetailsViewCell *cell = (RestaurantDetailsViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"restaurantDetailsCell" owner:self options:nil];
      cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
  }

  arrResponse =[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict];
  arr = [arrResponse objectAtIndex:0];

  dictio = [arr objectAtIndex:0];

  cell.cusineRestLabel.text = [[dictio valueForKey:@"restaurant_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  NSLog(@"cell is %@",cell.cusineRestLabel.text);

  //    cell.cusineRestLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"restaurant_name"];

  cell.cusineRestAddress.text = [dictio valueForKey:@"restaurant_streetaddress"];

  NSLog(@"cell is %@",cell.cusineRestAddress.text);

  cell.cusineDeliveryTime.text = [dictio valueForKey:@"restaurant_delivery"];

  NSLog(@"cell is %@",cell.cusineDeliveryTime.text);

  return cell;
}
```

after executing for the first time [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Really? Where is your question? Edit your question and ask in a proper way.

Comment: Reformat the code, ask a question, provide a useful error explanation (at what line),show some effort!

Comment: after return cell the control goes to closed bracket after that it should go up and reexecute all the lines but crashes

Comment: Hahaha, WHAT? Have you read our comments?

Comment: do not use a dictionary as data source. You will get the items in a random order because a dictionary is unordered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: So `dict` is, in fact, an array?  That's some terrible code.

Comment: Are arrResponse, dict, dictio etc. all instance variables? That's horrible. Instance variables should start with an underscore. And most likely these shouldn't be instance variables in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
  arrResponse =[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict];
  arr = [arrResponse objectAtIndex:0];
```

is a very strange way to write

```
  arr = (id)dict;
```

which looks not like a bug, but intentional obfuscation. So what is it: An array or a dictionary?