# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I setup my dataProvider Object in the storyboard
[image]

link it in the storyboard I get an error when i run it.

[TableApp.ItemListViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f84f6803a70'

but it is okay when it do it in code inside my ViewDidLoad

I could not figure out why please help me understand.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are incorrectly linking them.

you need to add `UITableViewDelegate` to your super Class

and in the `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

make sure you are linking the tableView as follows

[image: IMG1]. [image: IMG2]

you should have this!

[image: You should end up with this]