# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

Please help me, I am trying to convert UITextField to NSDate. Where is the mistake?

.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)   UITextField   *finishDateField;
@property (strong,nonatomic)  NSDate        *endDate;
```

.m

```
-(void) getDate{

    SaveAndLoadClass* Loader = [[SaveAndLoadClass alloc] init];
    [Loader loadSettings];
    self.finishDateField = [Loader dateField];
    [self firstCalculate];
}
-(void)firstCalculate{
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
        self.endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString: self.finishDateField.text];
        NSLog(@"datefromField:%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate: self.endDate]);
}
```

> -[__NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000002c620
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000002c620'

Comment: `finishDateField` not an IBOutlet, then how you are initialising it ?

Comment: I got it from another class; `self.finishDateField = [Loader dateField];` The Loader the object of another class

Comment: if `[Loader dateField]` returning a string, then the above is incorrect please use `[currentlySelectedTextField setText:[Loader dateField]];` this line to set text. It may remove your build errors.

Comment: So `[Loader dateField];` returns an UITextField ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple... You forgot to add .text after self.finishDateField

```
self.endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.finishDateField.text];//error here
```

Comment: If I do this, I have "Build Fail"

Comment: @sLav9n It should not fail check if you have any other errors in the project or may be try clean and build.

Comment: May be you have declared another property with the same name "finishDateField". Double check that.

Comment: No, i have only one "finishDateField" on this class

Comment: @sLav9n can you share .h and .m files?

Answer (score 0):

`dateFormat dateFromString:self.finishDateField` is the textfiled itself. You have to assign the content of the field:

```
self.endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.finishDateField.text]
```

Comment: If I do this, I have "Build Fail"

Comment: -[__NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000030700

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `textField` instead of string, your code should be like,

```
 self.endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.finishDateField.text];
```

And second thing your string that you enter in your textfield is in `dd MMMM yyyy` format as your date formatter is like this, otherwise you will not get date!

Comment: Yes, the "finishDateField" has value "21 Jule 2015"; if I put ".text", the build is fail

Comment: show your whole class! you are doing minor mistake somewhere!