# iOS 11: App is crashing only in iOS 11 not in the lower versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11

I am creating on camera application and I am constantly getting crash in iOS 11 but app is working fine in lower version of iOS. Crash I am getting in log console is as below:

```
-[__NSArrayI name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000446570
```

I haven’t use any dictionary or any array which contains key “name” and it is giving me this crash log.

Exception break point is also not helpful in this crash. I have used many arrays in my application but none of them are causing crash i think. I am now out of option.

I am using xCode 9 beta version and running app in iOS 11 beta 1 and 2. in both versions it is crashing.

Any help or conceptual solution will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: more info about the context, maybe...? your code seems buggy, are you still using MRR?

Comment: Which beta are you using? And maybe add a screenshot / code snippet of the breakpoint location even if you think its useless. Anything to provide a little more context would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I enable all break point but its not stopping at any specific line. I am attaching crash screenshot in my question.

Comment: @holex I am not using MRR. I am using xCode 9 beta version and running app in iOS 11 beta 1 and 2. in both versions it is crashing.

Comment: maybe you have to add some privacy key description in info.plist

Comment: I already added for camera, location, microphone, gallery these all i need and i added them,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error - tips

Comment: can you add symbolic breakpoint with -[__NSArrayI name]: it will help you to find who calling it exactly.Plus cmd + shift + K to delete cache before run.

Comment: Is it Thread1 that's crashing or another Thread? Is is crashing upon startup? If yes, set breakpoints in the application delegate to see if it manages to hit the breakpoints before crashing. Also print the instance that receives the selector, so we can see where it's being sent to. @holex What is MRR ?

Comment: @AjayGabani, you are still using ObjectiveC... and you don't know what MRR is? that is a kinda of manual memory management, and if you don't know the origin of the error, usually a wrong memory management throws such type of exceptions after you `release` an object and the memory block is re-allocated for another type of object, but you still keep /cast the original pointer of the old object and try to refer to it; it is very hard to recognise or catch but it is typical in ObjC with MRR.

Comment: @holex I know MRR. Its Lefteris who asked you about same. My app is crashing on startup but it executed my main view controller view will appear method successfully and from some where it is crashing. I will try Ali Kiran 's suggestion once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with my code. I added filters in my preview layer and one or more those filters are not supported in iOS 11 so it was crashing application.

Here is the code line which is crashing application without indicating anything.

```
[[previewView layer] setFilters:@[filterArray]];
```

Thank you all of you for your suggestions and helps.

I really appreciated it.

Comment: How you came to know that specific filter is not supported in iOS 11. I have similar issue with my framework but unable to find the exact line of crash even with exception breakpoint.

Comment: @Jaiswal Based on my error i checked that some naming is creating issue. So checked with each and every cases with trial and error. No specific technique to check this. :(