# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift

I suppose this question could be easily classed as a duplicate but can't find answer after searching.

inside `cellForRowAt` for my `tableView`

```
let chooseProfilePhotoPicker = ChooseProfilePhotoPicker(rootVC: self)
chooseProfilePhotoPicker.cropVC.delegate = self
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(chooseProfilePhotoPicker.iconImageViewTapped(_:)))
cell.iconImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

And the `ChooseProfilePhotoPicker` class:

```
class ChooseProfilePhotoPicker: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var rootController: UIViewController

    init(rootController: UIViewController) {
        self.rootController = rootController
    }

    func iconImageViewTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        var pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        rootController.present(myPickerController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

app crashes when I tap the iconImageView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **action** is supposed to run in in the instance of `ChooseProfilePhotoPicker` you have to set the **target** accordingly:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: chooseProfilePhotoPicker, action: #selector(chooseProfilePhotoPicker.iconImageViewTapped(_:)))
```