# Why gl-react not working in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use https://github.com/gre/gl-react-native and react-native-webgl in react-native(0.58.3) but it is not working, it show me error like this

"[tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Exception '-[RCTCxxBridge jsContextRef]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166d5740' was thrown from JS thread"

Here is my code

```
import { Shaders, Node, GLSL , GL} from 'gl-react'
import {Surface} from 'gl-react-native';
import GLImage from "gl-react-image";
import { WebGLView } from "react-native-webgl";

const shaders = Shaders.create({
  Saturate: {
    frag: GLSL`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec2 uv;
  uniform sampler2D t;
  uniform float contrast, saturation, brightness;
  const vec3 L = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
  void main() {
    vec4 c = texture2D(t, uv);
    vec3 brt = c.rgb * brightness;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(
      vec3(0.5),
      mix(vec3(dot(brt, L)), brt, saturation),
      contrast), c.a);
  }
  `
  }
});

    export const Saturate = ({ contrast, saturation, brightness, children }) =>
  <Node
    shader={shaders.Saturate}
    uniforms={{ contrast, saturation, brightness, t: children }}
  />;



render() {
    const filter = {
      contrast: 1,
    saturation: 1,
    brightness: 1
    }

    return (
     <Surface style={{ width: 500, height: 500, backgroundColor: "green" }}>
          <Saturate {...filter}>
            {{ uri: "https://i.imgur.com/uTP9Xfr.jpg" }}
          </Saturate>
        </Surface>
    );
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using Realm right? I have the same issue and debugging it with this breakpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error shows that the crash comes from Realm. More info here, maybe helpful even if you're not using Realm: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/2239